# EF CORE C#, inserta id autoincrementales con valores muy altos, aiuda

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, webapi, netcore

saben por que cuando inserto datos a un tabla, ef core los inserta con valores de 1 en 1 (todo bien), pero llega a presentarse el caso en que los ids autoincrementables se insertan con valores super altos, coloco la evidencia.

[image: evidencia]

Espero me puedan apoyar en resolver este problema, pues se ha presentado en todas mis tablas.

Comment: Mas alla de que el id no deberia importarte para nada, nunca, esto dudo que lo haga EF.. si son autonumericos, es la base de datos quien lo hace.

Comment: gbianchi que crees que se deba este error? quizás si sea algo preocupante pues del id 20423 se brinco hasta el 30241

Comment: No es ningun error. que te hace pensar que es un error? no se como insertas datos en tu base de datos, pero los numeros automaticos, si la base es compartida o en otros casos, se agarran por tramos, y luego puede ser que algunos tramos se descarten.... porque pensas que hay un error cuando un autonumerico es solo un indicador de fila, que no deberia servir para absolutamente nada mas que eso?

Comment: No es entity framework  es el gestor de base de datos el que hace eso, SQLSERVER

Comment: Una vez me pasó ese incremento muy extraño, lo rastree hasta una **query o trigger** (no recuerdo muy bien) que al intentar una **inserción fallida** incrementaba sí o sí el contador del **AUTO_INCREMENT**, tal vez te podría estar pasando lo mismo